# Почему не работают якорные ссылки?

Tags: wordpress, ссылки, редирект

Сайт на вордпресс, перестали работать якорные ссылки https://clusterfloor.ru/spc-%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82/#catalog__collection.

При попытке перехода открывается целевая страница, но сразу же происходит переадресация на главную. Страница без якоря открывается без проблем.

Я пробовал отключать плагины, чистить кэш, менять настройки в `.htaccess` на базовые, пересохранять и менять формат ссылок. Ничего из этого не помогло.

В чем может быть причина? Возможно ли что переадресация настроена у регистратора домена?

Comment: _Возможно ли что переадресация настроена у регистратора домена?_ - Нет. Браузер вообще не посылает хэш на сервер.

Comment: [Нет никакого редиректа](https://bertal.ru/index.php?a11392586/https://clusterfloor.ru/spc-%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82/#catalog__collection#h).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Возможно ли что переадресация настроена у регистратора домена?

Нет. Браузер вообще не посылает хэш на сервер.

> При попытке перехода открывается целевая страница, но сразу же происходит переадресация на главную.

[image: скриншот network doc]

[image: скриншот скрипта]

По идее эта ссылка должна вести на код, но она этого не делает, так что отлавливай это место другими способами.

Comment: в хедере было это
`if (window.location.href.indexOf('#') > -1) {
    window.location.replace('/');
}` без него все работает. спасибо!